# Space between characters for summation cases condition

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cases

I am using the following code for summation with cases:

```
$\sigma(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 if \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} > \theta and i = 0\\
    0, \textit{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
```

However for this code, there are no spaces between the characters when the LaTeX code is compiled. How do I insert space between the characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `&` to separate the state from its explanation, and use `\text` to denote text mode.

```
$\sigma(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} > \theta$ and $i = 0$}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
```

Syntactically, `if $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} > \theta$ and $i = 0$` is a sentence, albeit a sentence that contains two formulas.

Comment: Note that `\text{}` requires `amsmath` or `mathtools`. @Arun add `\usepackage{mathtools}` before `\begin{document}`.